# Why Is CRM Displaying A Section That Has Been Defined As Hidden?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Our client has an entity with multiple forms.  All the forms look virtually identical with the 40 same basic fields, split up among 5 different sections.  4 of the sections are defined as visible, but one isn't.  It contained the name of the entity (which is programmatically calculated from various fields, which explains why it is on the form but hidden) along with a couple other fields that are required by the JavaScript of the form, in order to process the business rules of the entity, but the actual business user don't care about.

Everything was working fine until we upgraded the on-premise version of CRM from rollup 11 to rollup 15.  Now, after the rollup, on one of the forms, for a particular subset of data, the hidden section is mysteriously being displayed.  I have tried everything I can think of, defaulting the section to being hidden, setting it to being hidden as the last function call of the onLoad JavaScript, even setting all of the fields within the hidden section as being hidden.  All to no avail.

Why Is CRM Displaying A Section That Has Been Defined As Hidden?

Comment: Does the hidden section contain a mandatory field?

Comment: @JamesWood What do you mean by mandatory?  Business Required?

Comment: Yes, I've hidden found sections that contain a business required field also become visible when the user attempts to save the record.

Comment: I've had the same issue as well @JamesWood, but this is occuring directly after the OnLoad, not after the OnSave.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to make all the fields in the hidden section read-only.  [More details here](http://www.dotnetdust.blogspot.com/2014/01/why-is-crm-displaying-section-that-has.html).